# How to convert a JsonObject object to a list of another object type

Tags: java, list, rest, arraylist

I have a service that will return a list of objects something like this:

```
{
      "myobject": [
        {
          "first" : "10",
          "second": 5.000
        },
        {
          "first" : "20",
          "second": 20.000
        },
        {
          "first" : "30",
          "second": 50.000
        }
      ]
    }
```

I take this object with this request

```
public String getMyObject() {

    String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(myUrl);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

I need to put this list inside a list of Objects of this type:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyObject{
    
    private String firstParam
    private String secondParam

}
```

How to do this? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is what you expect as a response object at this line:

`ResponseEntity<myObject[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url , myObject[].class);`

Instead you should ask for a MyDTO object since also your controller is returning a MyDTO object:

`ResponseEntity<MyDTO> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url , MyDTO.class);`

and retrieving the list with a

`List<MyObject> myList = myDTO.getMyObject();`

after extracting the `MyDTO` object from the `ResponseEntity` response object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I think I was not very clear in my question, I will try to improve it. I think it will be easier to try to help me.

Comment: I updated the question, now is it better to understand?

Comment: With the updatred question is clear that you have a deserialization problem.
Your json object can be represented in POJO like an object containing a field called `myobject` which is in fact a `List<MyObject>`
Also if you want to keep inside `MyObject` the fields named differently from the json object you need to annotate them with (if using jackson) @JsonProperty(name = <json-field-name>)

So if you declare your ResponseEntity as String then you have to call your parser to deserialize the string into actual POJOs with the structure above or parse the string yourself to create what you want

Comment: TKS MAN! ITS RIGHT!